# FIR to linear-phase FIR

Tags: matlab, finite-impulse-response, linear-phase

I am trying to convert an FIR impulse into linear-phase FIR impulse, I need to remove the phase response, so when it is applied to a sound it only changes the amplitude response.

Here is my code below:

```
clear all; 
close all;        
[x,fs]=audioread('impulse.wav')

s=fft(x)    
ph=angle(s)

amp=abs(s)    
s2=real(ifft(pol2cart(0,amp))) ; setting phase to zero

s2= circshift(s2,(round(length(s2)/2)))
plot(s2)

s2=s2/max(max(abs(s2)))

audiowrite('LinearPhaseImpulse.wav',s2,fs,'BitsPerSample',24)
```

- Is this the correct way of converting an FIR to a linear-phase FIR impulse response?
- How would one negate the phase so the FIR becomes linear-phase?

Comment: is this the correct way of converting an FIR to a linear phase FIR impulse response ? how would one negate the phase so the FIR becomes linear phase ?

Comment: No, it's not. The magnitudes of the frequency responses will only agree on the FFT grid, but not in between the grid points. If you do some zero-padding and windowing, the results will be better. I'll write up an answer as soon as I have some time to do so.

Comment: What you need is an all-pass filter to equalize/compensate the phase response such that the overall phase response is linear but the magnitude response remains unchanged. Here are some references: [link1](http://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/6034), [link2](http://www.iks.rwth-aachen.de/fileadmin/publications/loellmann06b.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting an arbitrary FIR filter into a linear-phase FIR with the same magnitude response is generally impossible. As mentioned in [msm's answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/34222/4298), this conversion must be done with an allpass filter, which must be an IIR filter, and only in those rare cases where you get appropriate pole-zero cancellations will the total filter be FIR. In general you'll end up with an IIR filter.

Having said that, there are possibilities to convert a given FIR filter into a linear-phase FIR filter with *approximately* the same magnitude response. By increasing the length of the linear-phase FIR filter, the approximation can be made arbitrarily good.

The method is similar to the one you implemented, but the crucial difference is zero-padding. You need to use an FFT length that is much greater than the length of the given FIR filter.

Below is an octave example explaining how it works. I chose a non-linear phase filter of length $30$, and approximated it by a length $39$ linear-phase FIR filter:

```
% come up with some non-linear phase FIR filter
[b,a] = butter(5,.3);
h = impz(b,a);
h = h(1:30);    % length 30
h = h(:)';

% do the FFT trick
N = 1024;       % FFT length (even!)
H = fft(h,N);
hlp = real(ifft(abs(H)));
hlp = [hlp(N/2+2:N),hlp(1:N/2)];

% windowing
Nw = 39;        % choose window length (odd!) = filter length
w = ones(1,Nw); % rect. window (choose another if you wish)
w = w(:)';
Nw2 = (Nw-1)/2;
hlp = hlp(N/2-Nw2:N/2+Nw2) .* w;

% plot
Hlp = fft(hlp,N);
n = (0:N/2)*2/N;
subplot(2,1,1), stem(h), hold on, stem(hlp,'r'), hold off
legend('NLP FIR', 'LP FIR')
subplot(2,1,2), 
plot(n,20*log10(abs(H(1:N/2+1))),n,20*log10(abs(Hlp(1:N/2+1))),'r')
legend('NLP FIR', 'LP FIR') ,grid on
```

The plot below shows the impulse responses of the two FIR filters, and the magnitude responses. The magnitude approximation could be further improved by choosing a longer filter length for the linear-phase FIR filter.

[image]