# Compute minimum phase version of a FIR

Tags: python, scipy, decomposition, minimum-phase, hrtf

I am working with [HRIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-related_transfer_function) filters, in particular I am trying to interpolate them.
One commod method in the literature to perform interpolation of HRIR is to use the minimum-phase decomposition and interpolate separately the minimum-phase part of the filter and then the all pass part.

You can find more here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/277879431_On_the_Minimum-Phase_Nature_of_Head-Related_Transfer_Functions

What I am trying to do is to convert my arbitrary HRIR FIR into a minimum phase one. In particular, I am working in Python and I have been using this [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.minimum_phase.html).

However while performing the conversion from the original FIR into the minimum-phase one I get the following error:

> RuntimeWarning: h does not appear to by symmetric, conversion may fail

With the following code:

```
min_phase_HRIR_0 = minimum_phase(hrtf[0], 'hilbert')
```

Where `hrtf[0]` is a 256 long FIR extracted from a HRIR database (in particular the [HUTUBS database](https://depositonce.tu-berlin.de/handle/11303/9429)).

If I plot the magnitude  of my original FIR and the minimum-phase one I get the following plot:
[image: Plot]

Which is obviously wrong since I am expecting the min phase and the original FIR to have the same magnitude spectrum.

I guess there is something wrong with the Scipy function. Is there anything for Python that converts a FIR into a minimum-phase version?

Comment: The documentation clearly states `Convert a linear-phase FIR filter to minimum phase`. HRIR are not linear phase and that's exactly what `h does not appear to by symmetric` means.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that, my bad. Is there something in Python to compute the min phase version of a FIR? (non restricted to linear phase)

Comment: Hmm... isn't it just bringing all zeros which are outside the unit circle to inside of unit circle?

Comment: @JuhaP: that would require you to identify poles and zeros first and that's quite difficult with a measured HRIR.

Comment: Creating a linear phase version of a filter is pretty trivial. You could do that first and then try your minimum_phase() magic method.

Comment: @DanSzabo My goal is to preserve the magnitude of the FIR, which I don't think it's preserved if I convert it into linear phase. I want to compute the minimum phase version of my FIR in order to perform a min-phase + all-pass decomposition. The min-phase version (at least theoretically) guarantees the same magnitude behaviour of the original filter

Comment: I am trying to compute is using the hilbert transform over the magnitude. So I am going to compute the phase phi as phi = imaginary{Hilbert{-log(|H(w)|}}, but I have to check if it works as expected.
Anyway, any already implemented function in Python  is well accepted.

Comment: Why wouldn’t a phase linear implementation preserve the magnitude response?

Comment: Also, I’d be way more concerned about the minimum phase converted magnitude response deviating than I would be a linear phase conversion.

Comment: I've already had a similar idea, but it seems that converting an arbitrary FIR to a linear phase, won't preserve the magnitude, As mentioned here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/34220/fir-to-linear-phase-fir/34222#34222 , also (maybe it is my bad) I have never heard of any conversion from arbitrary FIR to linear phase that preserves the filter magnitude characteristics.

Comment: On the other hand, it is well known that any spectrum can be made minimum phase by just reflecting the zeros outside the unit circle or by applying other methods such as cepstrum ecc... (you can find more here https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Conversion_Minimum_Phase.html and here https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/Creating_Minimum_Phase_Filters.html#sec:minphase ). So theoretically speaking, the minimum phase preserves exactly the original magnitude spectrum, in practice (obviously) there might be some differences due to numerical approximations/errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119440/discussion-between-dan-szabo-and-mattia-surricchio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used the Hilbert transform to compute the minimum-phase phase of my FIR.

I have used the following formula:
[image: Formula]

Where H is the spectrum of the desired filter.

Which has been used in:

1. [Individualisation d’indices acoustiques pour la synthèse
   binaurale](https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00012023v2/document)
2. [Phase Unwrapping for Spherical
   Interpolation of Head-Related
   Transfer Functions](https://iem.kug.ac.at/fileadmin/media/iem/projects/2011/zaar.pdf)
3. [Transformation characteristics of the external human ear](https://asa.scitation.org/doi/10.1121/1.381470)

However I am not sure of the results I got.

A follow up question discussing the results and implementation can be found here: [minimum-phase phase via Hilbert transform returned values](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/73117/minimum-phase-phase-via-hilbert-transform-returned-values)

Comment: what is the reference of your formula?

Comment: They're linked in the answer, you can find it in those papers I linked