# minimum-phase phase via Hilbert transform returned values

Tags: python, phase, hilbert-transform, minimum-phase, hrtf

Following my previous question: [HRIR Minimum phase](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/73060/compute-minimum-phase-version-of-a-fir/73116#73116) I managed to compute the minimum-phase phase of a FIR filter (in my particular case, HRTF filters).

However I am not sure of the phase values returned by my function.

The Python function is the following. It expects an arbitrary HRIR as input. I am using a 44100 long FFT to have the freqency bins perfectly aligned at integer frequencies at 44100Hz sampling rate (so for example a sinusoid at 1000Hz will have a magnitude of exactly 1 with no spectral leakage)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import hilbert
from scipy.fft import fft, ifft, fftfreq

def min_phase_coversion(HRIR):

    HRIR_fft = fft(HRIR,44100)

    xf = fftfreq(len(HRIR_fft), 1/44100)

    phase=np.angle(HRIR_fft)

    minimum_phase = np.imag(-hilbert(np.log(np.abs(HRIR_fft))))


    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(xf, phase)
    plt.plot(xf,minimum_phase)
    plt.plot()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

For the following plots I am using the [KEMAR MIT](https://sound.media.mit.edu/resources/KEMAR.html) dataset, in particular the plot have been computed for the HRIR at `[azimuth=144°, elevation=30°, distance=1.4m]`. The selected HRIR is the following (one per ear):
[image: HRIR]

[image: Magnitude]

Once I perform my minimum-phase computation using the above Python function, this is what I get (phase for a single ear):
[image: Phase]

However, looking at the plot, I can't understand the values returned by

```
np.imag(-hilbert(np.log(np.abs(HRIR_fft))))
```

Is the returned phase unwrapped? Or am i doing something wrong? The original phase "wraps" as expected once it gets over +3.14 or under -3.14 (+/- pi), while the minimum one doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I computed and compared the minimum phase HRIR and the original one.

This is my final code:

```
def min_phase_coversion(HRIR):
    '''

    :param HRIR: the desired HRIR impulse response to convert into minimum phase
    :return: the minimum phase version of the original HRIR
    '''

    HRIR_fft = fft(HRIR,44100)

    #computing magnitude, tested with sinusoid, it works.
    xf = fftfreq(len(HRIR_fft), 1/44100)

    fft_magnitude = np.abs(HRIR_fft/len(HRIR_fft))

    phase=np.angle(HRIR_fft)

    minimum_phase = np.imag(-hilbert(np.log(np.abs(HRIR_fft))))

    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(xf, fft_magnitude) #computing and plotting magnitude
    plt.plot(xf, phase, label='original phase')
    plt.plot(xf,minimum_phase, label='minimum phase')
    plt.legend()
    plt.plot()
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

    min_phase_HRIR = irfft(np.abs(HRIR_fft)*np.exp(1j*minimum_phase), 44100) # |H(w)|*e^(jPhi(w))

    HRIR_original = irfft(HRIR_fft, 44100)


    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(min_phase_HRIR[0:512], label="Min_phase", linewidth=0.5, marker='o', markersize=1) #ricostruisce bene
    plt.plot(HRIR_original[0:512], label="original phase", linewidth=0.5, marker='o', markersize=1) #ricostruisce bene
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


    plt.figure()
    min_phase_fft = fft(min_phase_HRIR, 44100)
    min_phase_mangnitude =  np.abs(min_phase_fft/len(min_phase_fft))
    plt.plot(xf,fft_magnitude)
    plt.plot(xf,min_phase_mangnitude)
    plt.show()

    return min_phase_HRIR
```

The results I get seem reasonable looking at the plots:
[image: minphase impulse response]

and the magnitude is the same as I expected (the original one and the min phase one are perfectly overlapping):

[image: magnitude]

However, I am not totally sure of the phase behaviour (as mentioned in my question) and its returned values.

Comment: Hi, I am very interested in this question. Finally did you opt for this implementation?

Comment: Yes, looks reasonable, but to this day im still not 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necobumping, but I think resolving this may be of general interest, because the minimum phase is quite a cool thing.

### unwrapped phase:

This seems to be exactly the case. The underlying [Kramers-Kroning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kramers%E2%80%93Kronig_relations) relation between imaginary part and real part of a function is a general property of causal signals. No phase wrapping involved.

### something wrong:

I can verify that you implementation is correct, although taking the imaginary part is puzzling at first, when starting with the simple definition of the minimum phase $\Phi_0$ and the magnitude of the spectrum, which you defined as $|\mathrm{HRIRfft}|$:

$$
\Phi_0=-\mathscr{H}(log(|\mathrm{HRIRfft}|)
$$

Looking at the Scipy docs for [hilbert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html#scipy.signal.hilbert) will lift that mystery.

Comment: So at the end of the day it was correct?